# How to use netperf on specific NIC port?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, networkcard

I have two servers, `SERVER` and `CLIENT`. Each server has its own onboard 1 GbE ports, and its own NIC with a 10 GbE port. `SERVER` and `CLIENT` are interconnected on both a 1 GbE switch (administrative traffic) and a 10 GbE switch (data traffic).

I want to test the performance of a specific 10 gigabit connection using `netperf`. How do I specify to use the 10 GbE NIC ports instead of the 1 GbE onboard ports?

Right now this is what I'm doing:

```
root@SERVER:~$ netserver
Starting netserver at port 12865
Starting netserver at hostname 0.0.0.0 port 12865 and family AF_UNSPEC

root@CLIENT:~$ netperf -H SERVER -l 15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the client use the IP address of the server that is assigned on the 10 gig interface as your argument to `netperf`. For example:

Server:

1 gig: 192.168.2.1
10 gig: 192.168.3.1

Client:

1 gig: 192.168.2.2
10 gig: 192.168.3.2

From client:

`netperf -H 192.168.3.1 -l 15`

Comment: So, on the server side, I assign static IPs to the 10 GbE interfaces as follows: `ifconfig eth2 192.168.2.1` and `ifconfig eth3 192.168.3.1` and then start separate netserver tasks for each port as follows: `netserver -L 192.168.2.1` and `netserver -L 192.168.3.1`. But what do I do on the client side to use the 10 GbE interface specifically?

Comment: Having distinct IPs on each interface on the server is right, yes. Your original netserver invocation is fine, though. It binds on all interfaces (0.0.0.0) by default. On the client side, just specify the IP that you assigned to the server's 10gig interface.

Comment: I see, so for example, I assign `192.168.3.1` and `192.168.4.1` to the 10 GbE interfaces on CLIENT and then execute `netperf -H SERVER -L 192.168.3.1 -l 15` on the client side?

Comment: Also: This is related but off-topic, but why do my 10 GbE interfaces lose their assigned IPs after a while? I'm using `ifconfig ethN 192.168.x.1`.

Comment: I have updated my answer with some addressing examples.

As for your other question, network interfaces typically need to be configured somewhere in /etc/ in order to remain persistent between reboots. The details are usually distribution specific.